# IOS print pdf with minimal margins

Tags: iphone, ios, uiprintpagerenderer

This must be quite simple but I can't seem to figure this out.

I've managed to implement the code for printing an PDF from my App. Problem is, the PDF has quite some whitespace around it and with the default margins... it's just not how I would like the page to come out of the printer.

So, I'm trying to reduce the margins to minimum. How would I go about this? Do I need to use a custom UIPrintFormatter, UIPrintPageRenderer or UIPrintPaper. In which method from UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate would I need to change things?

I know it can be done because when I print the PDF from Apple's iBook App, margines are significant less.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not quite solve the problem but I'm satisfied with the result now.
Actually I did not change anything, the reason why I asked this questing was because in the AirPrint simulator, my PDF printed with an excessive amount of white space / margin. But printing the PDF on an actual device did not have this problem.

So, if you run into this problem in the AirPrint simulator, try it on a real device/printer, changes are that everything prints fine.